# this pointer not working on radio selector

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to extract the inner html of a div that is after a radio button. Below, is my code:

```
$('input[class=selection1]:checked').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).next().next().text());
});
```

My HTML(This is just one of the many blocks):

```
<div class="box"><input type="radio" name="addr" class="selection1" value="3" style="width:20px;"> </input></div>
    <div class="box" style="width:300px;">
        <div class="normal">Demo Text</div>
    </div>
```

I want the Demo Text to be printed onto the console. However, a blank character is being printed. Could anyone please help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` in your sample, which one isn't needed?

Comment: Thanks, i've removed the extra div now

Comment: Ok, my answer should work for that sample then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very specific way to do this in a similar fashion as what you already have is: `$(this).parent().next().children().text()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no next sibling of radio here, try this:

```
console.log($(this).closest('.box').next('.box').html());
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution !! your answer made me realize that I was using next() in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to note that your selector will never  match your html.

You need to add checked attribute in you html

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="addr" class="selection1" value="3" style="width:20px;" checked></input>
</div>
<div class="box" style="width:300px;">
    <div class="normal">Demo Text</div>
</div>
```

In your Javasscript, then you can do this

```
$('input[class=selection1]:checked').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('.box').next().text());
});
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uu78cct1/